# segue: destination view controller weirdness

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

In my app, I use a storyboard and segues, and I often pass data to the destination view controller before doing the segue, as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setMyData:)]) {
        [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setMyData:) 
                                          withObject:myData];
    }
}
```

It works everywhere except in one place. The selector gets called, the data gets set, but when the segue completes and the destination controller appears, it doesn't have the data I just set. After printing the view controller's id in both the source and destination view controllers, I found that the `segue.destinationViewController` in the code above is a DIFFERENT instance of the view controller than the one that gets displayed. What's going on here?

**[UPDATE 1]**
I looked into the lifecycle of the destination view controller, and it first gets loaded during the segue execution, but AFTER I set the property on it! This means, that when I call `performSelector` on it, the view controller object is not initialized! This is why the data I set doesn't stick. t don't understand why is this the case, and why this same approach works in the other parts of my app.

**[UPDATE 2]**
Posting the code of `setMyData` by request. At first I didn't have this method at all, because `locationToOpen` is a public property. I only added it to ensure it gets called and to print the debug info.

```
- (void)setMyData:(MyData *)myData
{
    DLog(@"self: %@", (id)self);
    _myData = myData;
}
```

Comment: Is the destinationViewController a UINavigationController?

Comment: @adambinsz: it's a UIViewController that's embedded in a UINavigationController. The segue in the IB goes straight to the UIViewController.

Comment: Are you sure it's not going to the navigation controller? Try using [[segue.destinationViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: Do you mean [[ ( (UIViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] ? It returns null. BTW, I don't think it's even possible to segue to a UINavigationController. I get a runtime error when I do that.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to segue to a UINavigationController with a UIViewController embedded within it. I had a similar problem and replaced `segue.destinationViewController` with `[[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]` and it worked fine.

Comment: When I point my segue to the UINavigationController in the IB, I get this when the segue gets invoked: 

NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: Without changing the segue in Storyboards, does changing your code to what I've posted above fix the problem?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. In my case, `segue.destinationViewController` is just a UIViewController, so it doesn't have the selector `viewControllers` defined.

Comment: could you log all the view controllers you got by doing this: NSArray *vc = [[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers]; for (id tmp in vc) NSLog(@"%@",tmp); and post the result in your question?

Comment: additionally in the viewdidunload from the destination view controller type NSLog(@"View unloaded"); just to make sure that its not being unloaded and loaded again which would explain why its empty.

Comment: @LuisOscar! Ah! Looks like the view controller first gets loaded during the segue execution, but AFTER I set the property on it! I don't understand why is this the case, and why this same approach works in the other parts of my app. I'm still fairly new to Objective-C, and I'm not sure why is allows me to dereference a presumably uninitialized object.

Comment: @LuisOscar: The output of printing `[[segue destinationViewController] viewControllers]` is an error, like I expected :)
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LocationTableViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfdb3d80'`

Comment: Instead of performing a selector like that I would suggest setting the variables directly. If you do MyClassCOntroller *tmp = segue.destinationViewController; you can just access all the public variables on tmp directly or pass the object like this and on viewdidload use the object to fill the variables. (note that you have to add the header of the class to the first viewcontroller)

Comment: UINavigationController *nc = segue.desitnationViewController;
<your view controller type> *vc = nc.topViewController;
[vc setData]; this would be how I did it but it seems that some of the comments get to a similar solution.

Comment: I was just thinking, could you post the setMyData code?

Comment: @ScottSherwood: the problem is not in casting the controller object. It's that the controller object is not fully created by the time I call it (see the update 1 to the question).

Comment: @BlackRider do you mean that what you really do is [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setLocationToOpen:) 
                                          withObject:myData]; ?

Comment: @BlackRider Sorry I guess I wasn't being clear. I think he is trying to performSelector on the UINavigationController when intact he should be calling it on its topViewController. As I suggested this has been eluded to earlier, however the reason I suggested a new way of coding it (was a long shot) but I thought there must be something wrong with accessing the viewControllers themselves as I have never encountered this problem and indeed in prepare for segue the Controller being segued to should be setup and ready to receive information (since this is how Apple want you to handle delegation).

Comment: Or am I missing a part of the problem here? Also I feel it is better practice to cast in the prepare for selector since you should know they type your Segue is connected to, but that is just personal preference I think.

Comment: What is the relation between `setMyData:` and `setLocationToOpen:`? is myData a weak or strong property?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I renamed `locationToOpen` to `myData` for this question. They're the the same thing. I'll correct the code. BTW, all the properties are strong.

Comment: In case anyone comes here with this same situation, the solution proposed by @adambinsz actually works fine. In my app I set the segue to the nav controller and inside the - (void) prepareforsegue method wrote: `DestinationVC *vc = [[[segue destinationViewController] childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];`  Then I did a simple `[vc setMyString:@"content"];` and it worked perfectly. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it as follows -

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NextSegue"]) 
    {
        DestinationViewController *dest = [segue destinationViewController];

        dest.myData = self.myData; 
    }
}
```

And in the DestinationViewController.h, you should create a property -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DestinationViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSObject *myData;


@end
```

And also, make sure to synthesize the myData property in DestinationViewController.m -

```
@interface DestinationViewController ()

@end

@implementation DestinationViewController

@synthesize myData = _myData;

// other methods here

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is almost exactly the same that I do already in the code I've posted.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue. It turned out for me that the target ViewController property I was setting in my prepareForSegue: code was declared as weak because I had copied and pasted the property from one that InterfaceBuilder auto-created, but mine was not a Storyboard object. So my property was being released and zeroed by ARC on exit from prepareForSegue:. Making it a non-weak property fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the ViewController I was doing the segue to changed at some odd point,
after a looking around a bit it seems that the segue created a new ViewController.

To solve the data passing problem I used notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old and solution should be found. But since the final solution is not posted here, I would like to list one of the possible root cause (which is the one in my case). I had the same issue, trying to set the variable in the destination view controller of the segue. The root cause is that I forgot to instantiated ([[Class alloc]init]) the object variable. I need it in my case because I am setting the properties of the object instead of pointing to other object. Hope this help.